# Accessing element from list

Tags: c++, c++14

How can I access particular element from a list in C++? Basically programm would display list and ask to chose one element that would be moved to the end. For example there would be list: 2 4 5 8 3 4 if input would be 5 then result would be 2 4 8 3 4 5. Current code works only to move first element to the end. How to access any element from list and to move it to the end?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void printLists ( const list<int>& l2)
{
    cout  << "list1: ";
    copy (l2.begin(), l2.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
    cout  << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // create empty list
    list<int> list1;

    // fill list with elements
    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
        list1.push_front(i);
    }
    printLists( list1);

    // move first element to the end
    list1.splice(list1.end(),        // destination position
                 list1,              // source list
                 list1.begin());     // source position
    printLists(list1);

}
```

Comment: _"Particular"_ what exactly? By index, by value? How do you identify that particular element?

Comment: @ArminMontigny well, the question needs details to prove otherwise?

Comment: You could try `std::find()`, then `list::erase()` and finally `list::push_back`... if I understand the question well ...

Comment: It does not matter how to access that element, it just has to be moved to the end

Comment: I can not use erase because it has to be moved not recreated in a list

Comment: @Zero: "*Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.*" It does matter; we need to know what you have access to when you decide to move a thing. Do you have an iterator already, or do you need to find the iterator for the desired element? If it's the latter, how do you know which element is "desired"?

Comment: It looks like `splice` is the right tool. "Current code works only to move first element", well, yes, that's because you only pass it `list1.begin()`. If you want to move some other element you'll have to pass some other value for that argument. Hence all the duplicates about finding an iterator of a particular element in a list.

Comment: Element has to be identified by value

Comment: @NathanPierson I know that, Question is how can I access element 5 in a list 24579 to move it so list would be 24795

Comment: There's [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) but it's also something you can implement yourself by manually traversing the list and checking what the value of each element is.

Comment: Without error checking: ```#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
int main() { 
    std::list l{ 2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 4 };
    int k; std::cin >> k;
    l.splice(l.end(), l, std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), k));
    for (int n : l) std::cout << n << ' ';
}```